# AIMLStandard bot value cant be null path2 error

Tags: c#, winforms, io, chatbot, aiml

I am trying to use AIMLStandard which I installed from nuget and cant get past the first line. I added the config and settings directories with their files in the projects \bin\Release\aiml and \bin\Release\config folders.
the only code i have written is this, of course the configPath is truncated to fit it in...

```
string configPath = @"C:*\bin\Release\config\Settings.xml";
                Bot bot = new Bot(otherPath);
                bot.LoadAIMLFromFiles();
```

I am getting this bizzare error...

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at AIMLbot.Bot.get_PathToConfigFiles()
   at AIMLbot.Bot.loadSettings(String pathToSettings)
```

Comment: without the configPath, the null parameter name is path1, so possibly the aiml.xml path needs assigning?

Comment: i have a similar issue, this code seems to be some sort of abandonware, I checked the location of the current directory <Environment.CurrentDirectory> and it wasn't with the debug folder it was in an application install folder. I placed the aiml and config directories there and still i get the path1 error.